# Issue with building the OpenCV sln file

Tags: visual-studio-2010, opencv

I'm currently having trouble with building the OpenCV.sln file after generating them in Cmake. I am currently using windows 7 64 bit OS and VS 2010 Express. Also the OpenCV version I am using is 2.4.2 Once I open the OpenCV.sln file it would inform me that "solution folders are not supported in this version of the application".

Hitting the F5 button to build the .sln file would only yield in 8 successful build with the others tagged as failures. Is there anyway to fix this problem? thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In the newest CMake there is a 'use solution folders' option.  So before you generate, go to enable->solution folders and uncheck it.

Answer (score 0):

**Problem**

Solution folders are only supported in the non-express versions of Visual Studio. I had the same problem when I first tried to install mine.

Source: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/Vsexpressvc/thread/2a8e62c8-e14f-4027-8704-7d943c99303e

---

**Solution**

I used [this tutorial](http://opensourcecollection.blogspot.com/2011/04/how-to-setup-opencv-22-in-codeblocks.html) to get OpenCV to work.

It's not the latest version, but it worked marvelously well.